# Elasticsearch : get x percents results of matching search

Tags: pagination, elasticsearch

Is there a way get the X percents of hits of elastisearch search query?

For example: Get the 10% percent of oldest people (ordered by age)

if results count is 5010 this will results into an array of 501 hits

I'm talking about an easy way and not performing 2 queries :)

Comment: In your question, does 5010 represent the total number of documents in your index, and do you know that before hand?

Comment: no this is an example

Answer (score 1):

No, not with just a single search.

Don't be afraid of doing multiple requests. It's often better to work with several simple requests than a big and contrived one.

In this case, since you're sorting, you can get away with just using filters, after which a subsequent request will be plenty fast if the filter is cached. If you're concerned about performance, make sure you route the subsequent request to the same node, and it'll have what it needs cached already. (And do the initial search request with [search type `count`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html)).

Comment: You can also put 2 facets on the request that include one with no filters and the second with filters and get the answer in one request without the latency of both requests.